# Создание объекта зависящего от других объектов в джава

Tags: java

Имеется следующая задача - нужно создать объект ёмкость в основаниях которого могут быть такие фигуры как квадрат, прямоугольник, круг и тому подобное. Емкость должна быть наклонной с одинаковыми углами наклона во всех направлениях. (Я описал не всю задачу а только тот момент который у меня вызвал вопрос). Я написал следующие классы:

```java
public abstract class Container {
    private float volume;
    private Liquid liquid;
    private float height;
    private float weight;
}

public class InclinedContainer extends Container {
    private InclinedContainerBase largeBase;
    private InclinedContainerBase littleBase;

    public InclinedContainer(InclinedContainerBase largeBase,
                             InclinedContainerBase littleBase) {
        this.largeBase = largeBase;
        this.littleBase = littleBase;
    }
}
```

Я реализовал класс `InclinedContainer`, он состоит из двух оснований - большего и меньшего. Классы оснований написаны и имеют общий интерфейс `InclinedContainerBase`. И на этом этапе я столкнулся с проблемой, ведь в данном случае пользователь моих классов сможет создать ескость в которой будет верхнее основание квадрат а нижнее круг - а этого не должно быть. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как правильно реализовать что бы при создании объекта `InclinedContainer` в конструктор можно было передавать только объекты одного типа, если в качестве первого параметра консруктора был передан квадрат, то и в качестве второго так же должен быть передан квадрат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каждой фигуре - свой интерфейс.

Comment: нужна проверка именно на этапе компиляции? Или runtime exception тоже допустимо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте `InclinedContainer` параметризированным типом:

```
public class InclinedContainer<T extends InclinedContainerBase> extends Container {
    private T largeBase;
    private T littleBase;

    public InclinedContainer(T largeBase,
                             T littleBase) {
        this.largeBase = largeBase;
        this.littleBase = littleBase;
    }
}
```

Тогда типы с разными базами будут отличаться:

```
CircleBase littleBase = ...;
CircleBase largeBase = ...;
InclindedContainer<CirleBase> cirleBaseContainer = new InclindedContainer<CirleBase>(largeBase, littleBase);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, хорошее решение! думал об этом но чего то показалось что не получится и перестал об этом думать)) а нужно было попробовать)))

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Circle extends Container {
}

public class Square extends Container {
}

public class InclinedContainer extends Container {
    private Container largeBase;
    private Container littleBase;

    public InclinedContainer(Circle largeBase, Circle littleBase) {
        this.largeBase = largeBase;
        this.littleBase = littleBase;
    }

    public InclinedContainer(Square largeBase, Square littleBase) {
        this.largeBase = largeBase;
        this.littleBase = littleBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: мне кажется что это решение не совсем подходит для моего случая, наверное это из-за того что я описал не всю задачу, а только часть. Классы квадрат, круг и так далее являются базами контейнера а не самим контейнером, таким образом, наклонный контейнер имеет ссылки на базы а не на контейнеры. Возможно я не понял вашей идеи.

Comment: добавил диаграмму в вопрос